# What to do if i get cannot find symbol class onclicklistener error?

Tags: java, android

I am writing another program but this time on Android Studio as an app in Java. Now I am getting following error; error: cannot find symbol class OnClickListener

How do I fix this? Here is my code:

```
package tegabyte.testprogramm;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText firstNumber;
    EditText secondNumber;
    TextView addResult;
    Button btnAdd;

    double num1,num2,sum;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        firstNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtBase);
        secondNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNikotin);
        addResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtResult);
        btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                num1 = Double.parseDouble(firstNumber.getText().toString());
                num2 = Double.parseDouble(secondNumber.getText().toString());
                sum = num1 / 20 * num2;
                addResult.setText(Double.toString(sum));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: use new View.OnClickListener()

Comment: Then you import it `import android.view.View.OnClickListener;`. The IDE is probably even suggesting you to do so

Comment: See my comment under Anonymous post.

Comment: Add line `import android.view.View.OnClickListener;` below all import list

Comment: I tried doing so, but android.view.View was the right thing to import. I dont need OnClickListener behind that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead.I think you have not imported the OnclickListener.Either import it or use like this.

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            num1 = Double.parseDouble(firstNumber.getText().toString());
            num2 = Double.parseDouble(secondNumber.getText().toString());
            sum = num1 / 20 * num2;
            addResult.setText(Double.toString(sum));
        }
    });
```

Also add import statement at the top like this for the view class `import android.view.View;`

Comment: When I try to build it now, it tells me error: package View does not exist. What to do in this case?

Comment: Add the view import statment.

Comment: I did so. (import android.view.View.OnClickListener;)
still same error.

Comment: Oh hold on. I had to import android.view.View without OnClickListener. I got it fixed now. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't imported the OnClickListener. In addition, there are multiple OnClickListeners in different SDK packages. The one I assume you're looking for is the one in `View`. So instead of `new OnClickListener()`, write `new View.OnClickListener()`

Answer (score 1):

OnClickListener need to identify of which OnClickListener to perform click so add `View`

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                num1 = Double.parseDouble(firstNumber.getText().toString());
                num2 = Double.parseDouble(secondNumber.getText().toString());
                sum = num1 / 20 * num2;
                addResult.setText(Double.toString(sum));
            }
        });
```

or when you type `btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new On` 
you get list of hints than select `View.OnClickListener()`